# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: c#, xml, compiler-errors, windows-phone-8-emulator

When I compile to a windows 8 phone I keep getting this error.

I want to output some XML from my API URL.

I get the right XML-format when I use my URL in the browser but keeps getting this error when I compile in Visual studio 2013 Premium.

```
private void WebQuestion()
{
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    // Add event handlers when webbclienten received answers
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += wc_OpenReadCompleted;

    // Invoking web service asynchronously and let the answer be handled 
    string URL = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=885221892&key=D38259AC7F57D17B10F73A76C1873DD2&format=XML";

    wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(URL));  
}

void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        something
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the URL require authentication? Maybe you logged on in your browser, but you didn't in the app?

Comment: No It doesn't require any log in what I can see or have done.

Comment: Try the following.  In the emulator try the same URL, does it succeed?  Also to you have the networking capability enabled in the manifest?